# Submit HTML form array to PHP using CFHTTP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to submit a form using CFHTTP to a PHP page - everything is working properly except for one form field that is using arrays.

The HTML code in the form is

```
<select name="groupselect[]" id ="groupselect" size="10" multiple="multiple">
<option value="26713">X-Men</option>
</select>
```

When I submit using CFHTTP all of the other form fields are submitted and recognised, but not this one.

I have tried

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect[]" value='26713'>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect" value='26713'>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect[0]" value='26713'>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect[]" value='Array ( [0] => 26713 )'>
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect" value='Array ( [0] => 126713 )'>
```

I have tried serialising, I have tried WDDX, I have tried everything I can think of and have had no luck. What am I overlooking? At the moment I only need to submit one value using this field, but in the future I may need to submit multiple values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT AFTER FIRST COMMENT

I did some more debugging and now I am more puzzled! When I submit the form manually $_Post returns:

```
Array
(
    [groupselect] => Array
        (
            [0] => 26713
        )

)
```

Then I submitted the form using **cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect[]" value='26713'** and the $_Post returned the exact same response! When I take the square brackets out, it shows me just a variable, not an array...

So, if that is working I guess I need to test some more with the live site and see why it isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to debug this a bit to actually find out what is going on.

It might be that `cfhttpparam` is not able to use the same name multiple times or is ignoring the HTML standard and disallows characters like `[` or `]` (this is an assumption only, I haven't used cfhttp lately).

To debug this you can inspect which post-data is actually transferred to your PHP script by reading it:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This will return the whole post-data that has been submitted to your script. If you dump it, you might find out more what is going on.

Alternatively you can debug this by using a network sniffer and inspecting the data that goes over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

OK - it turns out that the way to do this in ColdFusion is the most obvious way:

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="groupSelect[]" value='26713'>
```

However, for the ColdFusion programmers out there, PHP is case sensitive when it comes to variable names...

So while my name="groupSelect[]" wasnt working, name="groupselect[]" works perfectly!

Hakre, thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the suggestion of debug, and hopefully this helps someone else in the future!